# create multiple columns with apply on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to add several columns based on value of columns and condition check,
I'm retrieving the good data but I cannot add the columns, maybe it s not possible with apply(x,1,fun) but only with apply(x,2,fun) ?
Thx for your enlightenment

```
df <- data.frame(id = 411:420,
                 value = c(10,0,25,0,32,66,45,88,0,23),
                 prod =  c(500,300,400,600,0,800,400,300,200,0)
                 )

add_coll <- function(x) {

if (x["value"] >0  & x["prod"] > 0) {

  varname_v <- paste0("col_",x["id"],"_v")
  varname_p <- paste0("col_",x["id"],"_p")

  print(varname_v)
  print(varname_p)

  df[, varname_v] <- x["value"] #not working
  df[, varname_p] <- 55 #not working
  df$"test" <- 44 #not working

}

else {

  print("not creating columns")
}

}


apply(df,1,add_coll )
```

this is what I am expecting :

```
df_expected <- data.frame(
                 "id" = 411:420,
                 "value" = c(10,0,25,0,32,66,45,88,0,23),
                 "prod" =  c(500,300,400,600,0,800,400,300,200,0),

                 "col_411_v" =  c(10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_411_p" =  c(500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_413_v" =  c(0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_413_p" =  c(0,0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_416_v" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,66,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_416_p" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,800,0,0,0,0),
                 "col_417_v" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,45,0,0,0),
                 "col_417_p" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,400,0,0,0),
                 "col_418_v" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,0,0),
                 "col_418_p" =  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,300,0,0)

                 )

    id value prod col_411_v col_411_p col_413_v col_413_p col_416_v col_416_p col_417_v col_417_p col_418_v col_418_p
1  411    10  500        10       500         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
2  412     0  300         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3  413    25  400         0         0        25       400         0         0         0         0         0         0
4  414     0  600         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5  415    32    0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
6  416    66  800         0         0         0         0        66       800         0         0         0         0
7  417    45  400         0         0         0         0         0         0        45       400         0         0
8  418    88  300         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0        88       300
9  419     0  200         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
10 420    23    0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: You can create your new column names like this: `df[, paste0("col_41",c("1_v","1_p","3_v","3_p","6_v","6_p","7_v","7_p","8_v","8_p"))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against writing to (global) environment from within the apply "loop". If you really want to do that, you can always use a nice clear `for` loop.

The way I would recommend using `apply` in your case is create a data.frame with additional columns and then append them to `df`. Then there's some long to wide trickery going on. Feel free to examine each step individually.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id = 411:420,
                 value = c(10,0,25,0,32,66,45,88,0,23),
                 prod =  c(500,300,400,600,0,800,400,300,200,0)
)

add_coll <- function(x) {

  if (x["value"] >0  & x["prod"] > 0) {

    varname_v <- paste0("col_",x["id"],"_v")
    varname_p <- paste0("col_",x["id"],"_p")

    return(data.frame(varname_v, varname_p))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(varname_v = NA, varname_p = NA))
  }
}

out <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = add_coll)
out <- do.call(rbind, out)

xy <- cbind(df, out)

xywide <- pivot_wider(xy, names_from = varname_v, values_from = value)
xywide <- xywide[, colnames(xywide) != "NA"]
xywide <- pivot_wider(xywide, names_from = varname_p, values_from = prod)
xywide <- xywide[, colnames(xywide) != "NA"]
xywide[is.na(xywide)] <- 0

res <- merge(df, xywide)
res

    id value prod col_411_v col_413_v col_416_v col_417_v col_418_v col_411_p col_413_p col_416_p
1  411    10  500        10         0         0         0         0       500         0         0
2  412     0  300         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3  413    25  400         0        25         0         0         0         0       400         0
4  414     0  600         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
5  415    32    0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
6  416    66  800         0         0        66         0         0         0         0       800
7  417    45  400         0         0         0        45         0         0         0         0
8  418    88  300         0         0         0         0        88         0         0         0
9  419     0  200         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
10 420    23    0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   col_417_p col_418_p
1          0         0
2          0         0
3          0         0
4          0         0
5          0         0
6          0         0
7        400         0
8          0       300
9          0         0
10         0         0
```

If you were to go the `for` loop way, this would be one way of going about it. Basically creating a ghost data.frame with all zeros and then filling in the data should the row match your criteria. The up side of this method is that it's very extensible. But it is using `cbind` in a way that may be inefficient for rather large datasets.

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  myrow <- df[i, ]

  temp.cols <- dummy.template
  colnames(temp.cols) <- c(
    paste0("col_", myrow$id, "_v"),
    paste0("col_", myrow$id, "_p")
  )

  if (myrow$value > 0 & myrow$prod > 0) {
    temp.cols[i, 1] <- myrow$value
    temp.cols[i, 2] <- myrow$prod

    df <- cbind(df, temp.cols)
  }
}

    id value prod col_411_v col_411_p col_413_v col_413_p col_416_v
1  411    10  500        10       500         0         0         0
2  412     0  300         0         0         0         0         0
3  413    25  400         0         0        25       400         0
4  414     0  600         0         0         0         0         0
5  415    32    0         0         0         0         0         0
6  416    66  800         0         0         0         0        66
7  417    45  400         0         0         0         0         0
8  418    88  300         0         0         0         0         0
9  419     0  200         0         0         0         0         0
10 420    23    0         0         0         0         0         0
   col_416_p col_417_v col_417_p col_418_v col_418_p
1          0         0         0         0         0
2          0         0         0         0         0
3          0         0         0         0         0
4          0         0         0         0         0
5          0         0         0         0         0
6        800         0         0         0         0
7          0        45       400         0         0
8          0         0         0        88       300
9          0         0         0         0         0
10         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I confirm the part of wild trickery there, I do understand the first part but, yes this is a bit complicated for my need I guess I will go  with a for loop, do you maybe have good links related to it ?

Comment: @krifur I think your approach with `apply` is fine, just don't use it for writing outside of its environment. I just might add a `for` loop solution in the evening. Please ping me if I forget.

Comment: @krifur see if my changes suit your needs.

Comment: Thx i ve benn doing quite the same things as you with the for loop, I will try to replicate the same results when I will have time with the apply/pivot_wider solution

Answer (score 1):

You could create a column with row number, get the data in wide format and bind the columns to original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(value, prod), 
              values_fill = list(value = 0, prod = 0)) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .) %>%
  mutate_at(-(1:3), ~replace(., prod <= 0, 0))


#    id value prod value_411 value_412 value_413 value_414 value_415 value_416 ...
#1  411    10  500        10         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#2  412     0  300         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#3  413    25  400         0         0        25         0         0         0 ...
#4  414     0  600         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#5  415    32    0         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#6  416    66  800         0         0         0         0         0        66 ...
#7  417    45  400         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#8  418    88  300         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#9  419     0  200         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
#10 420    23    0         0         0         0         0         0         0 ...
```

Comment: Thx that s very intersting as well, but I need to create the columns only if value and prod are > 0, I also have others conditions with others columns...I probably can filter the data berfore pivot_wider but not sure how i will get back the whold df after

Comment: @krifur I have updated the answer to include those changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try this solution in future to see if it fit my needs